# Python Kubernetes SDK get image and pods status of Replica Set

Tags: python, kubernetes

I want get image name and pods status of Replica Set name by [python k8s SDK](https://pypi.org/project/kubernetes/)

Currently  I get the data manually from k8s UI dashboard:
[image]

I write code for get service (Replica Set) data but I didn't find any information of images or pods status of the service

```
config.load_kube_config()
api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()
services_items = api_instance.list_namespaced_service(namespace=namespace).items
```

Answer (score 2):

`Deployment`, `ReplicaSet`, etc, belong to the `apps/v1` API, not to the core API:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
api = client.AppsV1Api()

deployment_list = api.list_namespaced_deployment(namespace="foo")
# status of the first deployment in the list
print(deployment_list.items[0].status)

rs_list = api.list_namespaced_replica_set(namespace="bar")
# image of the first container of the first replica set in the list
print(rs_list.items[0].spec.template.spec.containers[0].image)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are querying for a `Service`.

You should be using `api_instance.list_namespaced_pod` to get Pods and their images or `list_namespaced_deployment` for Replica information.

Comment: There is no list_namespaced_deployment. Error : 'CoreV1Api' object has no attribute 'list_namespaced_deployment'